# What's best practice to store a value for spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple micro service built with Spring boot. It contains a scheduled task and I need to keep last scheduled task date for next scheduled task. As the service will be stopped for update or any unexpected reason, please advise what's the best practice to store this value at local? Thanks

Comment: where is this microservice deployed, public cloud?

Comment: it's going to deploy to aws

Comment: The best practice  is to use a distributed caching system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several possible solutions:

- write to a file, if you can write to filesystem
- write to a database, if you are using it
- make an HTTP request to another microservice which will keep your last record

Answer (score 1):

As the application will be deployed on AWS, you can use the [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). You could specify the key-value pair and update the value on every successful scheduled update. This way even if the EC2 instance (that has the application deployed) is terminated still these key-value pairs would not be impacted.

You could also use an S3 bucket and write this in a file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to store application data, but the choice boils down to how flexible would you want the solution to be. Similar to your usecase,  Spring Batch Admin (Now discontinued), was using MySql DB. So that it can keep the track of the record processed, and can continue the processing from the last point.

It can be as easy as writing the data to a file that can help you identify the last record which was processed, or to store it in a datastore like Redis, MySql or MongoDB.

So if you do not have any DB which you are using, storing an identifier of last processed record to a file would do the trick, if you are already using some type of data store like, MySql, MongoDB or Redis.

It would be *better* to store data into this datastore as data storage becomes abstracted from an application-specific logic or format and can be queried and/or modified externally if needed. This make the solution more modifiable as it's not tightly bound with the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid saving any of your most looked up data on the filesystem. This will slow down your application in case of hundreds of concurrent reads. Try to rely upon persistence cache.

- The first preference should be in-memory for all reads. You can asynchronously write into your in-memory and persistent cache. In case of application failure, you should use other performant caches built for this purpose. At the time of the reboot, reload your in-memory cache from persistent one.
- Persistent Cache eg: Elasticsearch, Redis. This will boost your application performance and will be much more scalable.